# How to store node script output into azure task variable

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am trying to store output of a node script into an azure task variable.

Came across this question [Return a value from node.js script in azure pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71833899/return-a-value-from-node-js-script-in-azure-pipeline) and based on this I have created a simple yml as below. But when I run this yml, script itself is not running, whereas If I run node test.js directly without setting task variable it is working fine and I can see the output. Not sure what am I doing wrong here, can anyone please point me in the right direction. Thanks

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: "testRepo"
      type: git
      name: project/repo

trigger: none

stages:
  - stage: Test
    variables:
      Test_Result: ''
    jobs:
    - job: TestJob
      displayName: Test
      steps:

      - checkout: self
      - checkout: testRepo

      - script: |
          npm install
        workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\testrepo

      # Not working - script not running
      - script: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Test_Result]$(node test.js)"
        workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\testrepo
```

**Output for above:**

[image]

**Output when node test.js is used without setting task variable**

```
- script: |
     node test.js
  workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\tp-ui-caseMgmtV8
```

[image]

Comment: @dudewad I tried to follow your post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71833899/return-a-value-from-node-js-script-in-azure-pipeline, but its not working for me. Sorry to tag you here as I dont have permission to add a comment in your post. Can you able to help me on this. Thanks

Comment: Have you got a chance to check the answer? If you need more help, please share it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the variable Test_Result in the next task instead of in the same task.

You can't set and use the same variable in the same task.
The set variables will take effect starting from the next task.

According to your logs, you are using windows agent. You need to replace -script with -bash.
Bash works for both windows and ubuntu agent.

```
 resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: "testRepo"
      type: git
      name: project/repo

trigger: none


stages:
  - stage: Test
    variables:
      Test_Result: ''
    jobs:
    - job: TestJob
      displayName: Test
      steps:

      - checkout: self
      - checkout: testRepo
      # bash works for windows and ubuntu agent
      - bash: |
          npm install
        workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\testrepo

      - bash : |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Test_Result]$(node test.js)"
        workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\testrepo

      - bash: |
          echo "$(Test_Result)"
```